# Django: If an object from a database is deleted do the remainer objects keep the same id/order?

Tags: sql, django

This might be a stupid question but here I go:
I have a SQLite database with Django. Let's say in one table i have four objects:

```
ID=1 name=dog
ID=2 name=cat
ID=3 name=lion
ID=4 name=rat
```

If I were to delete an object let's say

```
 animals.objects.get(id=3).delete()
```

Do the id's from the other objects change? Would it be:

```
ID=1 name=dog
ID=2 name=cat
ID=3 name=rat
```

They change right?
I am supposing they do.
And if they do is this so in other databases like MySQL?

Comment: No, they don't change. That would be horrifying. Primary keys should never change. Imagine the URL https://stackoverflow.com/users/13647086 pointing to a different user and not you, because someone else deleted their account and you are now user #13647085.

Comment: this is `ID` created by you,not `rowid` in some database,`rowid` would change base on location.but `ID` like other field in database created by you,it will not change until you change it.

Comment: @nay so if the id is not directly created by me does it change?

Comment: no,the important thing is not created by you or not.I said that is intend to different the `rowid`.in mysql the usually auto changed column is `timestamp change on update`.after all you should understand the data would not change until you change it manually or change by rule you setup.